# Postgresql: Query using multiple attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query with Postgresql. Unfortunately, the attributes in the attribute_table are listed as rows instead of columns which makes it harder to pull. I want to pull a count based on the three attributes I have listed below (1000 = gender - 2 = female, 1001 = age group - 5 = 55-64, 1002 = household size = 1). How do I adjust this query so that it only gives me one row vs three rows of the same personal_ID? Also when I use this query, it doesn't pull any values but if I put only 1 attribute it works.

```
select sa.country_id ,count(distinct sa.personal_id ) 
from study_table sa ,attribute_table a 
where sa.country_id =a.country_id and sa.personal_id =a.personal_id 
and to_char(sa.mailing_date,'yyyy-MM')='2021-01' 
and attribute_id =1000  and a.attribute_number =2 
and attribute_id =1001  and a.attribute_number =5
and attribute_id =1002  and a.attribute_number =1 
and study_type ='Wave' 
and status not in ('NEW','EXCLUDED','ERROR') 
group by sa.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Second, your `WHERE` conditions are contradictory.  You need `OR`s . . . and then a `HAVING` for the final filtering:

```
select sa.country_id ,count(distinct sa.personal_id ) 
from study_table sa join
     attribute_table a 
     on sa.country_id = a.country_id and
        sa.personal_id = a.personal_id 
where to_char(sa.mailing_date,'yyyy-MM') = '2021-01' and
      ( (attribute_id = 1000 and a.attribute_number = 2) or
        (attribute_id = 1001 and a.attribute_number = 5) or
        (attribute_id = 1002 and a.attribute_number = 1) 
      ) and
      study_type ='Wave' 
      status not in ('NEW','EXCLUDED','ERROR') 
group by sa.country_id
having count(distinct attribute_id) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your attribute_table follows an Entity-Attribute-Value. (IMHO that is an extremely bad **bad** plan - but if that is what you got that is what you deal with).  So to get/validate/set 3 attributes you need to reference that table 3 times in the query -once for each attribute.

```
select  sa.country_id 
     , count(distinct sa.personal_id ) 
  from study_table sa 
  join ( select g.personal_id
           from attribute_table g                    
           join attribute_table ag on ag.personal_id = ag.personal_id
          join attribute_table hs on hs.personal_id = hs.personal_id
          where 1=1
           and (g.attribute_id =1000  and g.attribute_number =2)
           and (ag.attribute_id =1001 and ag.attribute_number =5)
           and (hs.attribute_id =1002 and hs.attribute_number =1)
        ) sf                                       
    on sf.personal_id = sa.personal_id              
 where 1=1
    and to_char(sa.mailing_date,'yyyy-mm')='2021-01' 
    and sa.study_type ='Wave' 
    and sa.status not in ('NEW','EXCLUDED','ERROR')
group by sa.country_id;
```

The above of course assumes the column names study_type and status originate in the study table - seems likely.
But if not you will need 2 more references to the attribute table.

Hint: Always use tables aliases on ALL column references.